# How to use a custom adapter in FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know if there is a way to use a custom list adapter layout in  FirebaseListAdapter.

```
final ListView tutorList_id = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentActivity_tutorList_listView);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://some_name.firebaseio.com/users");
    FirebaseListAdapter<Users> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Users>(this, Users.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {


        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Users user, int i) {


            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(user.getFullName());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(user.getInterests());


        }
    };
    //Bind the list adapter to  listView
    tutorList_id.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From the above code , instead of using two_line_list_item or simple_list_item_2, i want to create a custom adapter class so that i am able to customize my list view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for an example of how to use a custom layout (i.e. `R.layout.yours`) with the `FirebaseListsAdapter`, have a look at the sample app that comes with FirebaseUI: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/RecyclerViewDemoActivity.java#L82

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, this example is exactly what am looking for

Answer (score -1):

Insted of  two_line_list_item or simple_list_item_2 replace the layout with your custom layout and populate the view